# PHP - Select a table and add to array (more than that)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

**EDIT - SOLUTION:**

```
$pdo->fetchAll();
```

Table columns:
id
content

In this table I just add various contents and I'm using this code to select and add to array:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare("SELECT content FROM content_small WHERE id > 0 AND id < 15");
$pdo->execute();
$result['content'] = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($result['content']) {
    $content['slide_title'] = $result['content'][0];
    $content['who_we_are'] = $result['content'][1];
}
print_r($result['content']); //this is to test only
```

Right now I got results but my array print this:

```
Array
(
    [content] => Content test
)
```

The problem is that all results are from ***column content***.

I know this isn't the best practice but its a simple thing that I'm doing.
Can you help me to find a solution?
Things I tried:
- Change fetch type

Comment: `fetch ` gives you only the last row use `fetchAll`

Comment: I just edited right now. I did this and works. Thank you! @FerhadOthman

Comment: Since this question is solved by typing 3 more characters, it has the same value as a "off-topic - typo" question.  Rather than voting to close this as a typo, I might ask you to delete this question (while there are no answers posted).

Comment: You are not meant to write the answer in your question.